# NOT IN Performing too slow with 10M+ rows in second table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a list that is not exist in a second table. I saw various Q&A and blog. Most of them suggested NOT IN and LEFT JOIN. As I have to setup a filter on second table I preferred NOT IN with sub-query. My Second table contains 10M+ rows. I am trying the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.username, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4, t1.column5
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.username NOT IN  (
            SELECT DISTINCT t2.username
            FROM table2 t2
            WHERE timestamp >= ". $activityDate ." 
              AND timestamp < ( DATE_ADD( ". $activityDate ." , INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) )
            )
AND t1.column2 = 'Dhaka' AND t1.column3 <> 'India'
GROUP BY t1.username
ORDER BY t1.username DESC
```

Sometimes it showing `#2004 Server has gone away` error.

Is there any way to speedup the result for faster response?

Comment: Show the `show create table [table] ` statements of the tabels and output of `explain [your_query]`

Comment: DISTINCT t2.username .... ....  GROUP BY t2.username in one select query.. You want the remove duplicated username you dont need DISTINCT and GROUP BY.. i advise you to remove the GROUP BY because you dont have aggregates in your query

Comment: EXPLAIN returned two rows. The primary contain 8k+ rows and the dependent contains 15k+ rows

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the lack of schemas.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.username, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4, t1.column5
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username 
    AND t2.timestamp BETWEEN " . $startDate . 
    " AND " . $endDate . "
WHERE t2.username IS NULL
...
```

Ensure that username and timestamp columns are indexed.
Precalculate enddate, there's no need to make the SQL server do it

Comment: Performance increased little bit but still taking more than 2 minutes. I am new developer. If I execute two query separately its taking just seconds to execute. Is there any way to cross match data from those two table in php or JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through the returned recordsets recursively in your application, but I don't believe that will result in any performance gain since you'll lose the performance boost that indexing on a SQL server will give you.  You need to run EXPLAIN SELECT ... and see where you may be able to optimize by better indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `SELECT DISTINCT` isn't needed, and depending on the data it could be doing a lot of work. But I think the real problem is evaluating the timestamp of *24 hours from now* over and over again.

```
DATE_ADD( ". $activityDate .", INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
```

Unless you have a clever database, that function needs to run once every row. Can you calculate the timestamp outside of the query?

Comment: Can you explain how I can use the timestamp outside the query?

Comment: I don't know your timestamp format, but use PHP to make another variable that is $activityDate + 24 hours.

Comment: I have tried only `WHERE timestamp > CURDATE()` instead of using timestamp twice for performance checking. Still there is no luck

Comment: Well, my theory might still be right, because 'CURDATE()' has to run every row. Can you try a fixed timestamp?

Comment: Tried `WHERE timestamp > '2017-01-19'` Still no luck

Comment: Darn it. Did you already get rid of that inner SELECT DISTINCT and the GROUP BY statement?

Comment: The inner select or sub query is returning only in 0.17 second. Yes I have removed the GROUP BY also